# sql works in libreoffice base but not libre basic

Tags: sql, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-base

I have a classic question about getting the latest record from a table. Here is the statement:

```
SELECT t1.Item, t1.Price, t1.ODate
FROM Order AS t1
JOIN ( (SELECT Item, Price, Max(ODate) As MaxDate
        FROM Order
        GROUP BY Item ) As t2 )
ON t1.Item = t2.Item and t1.Odate = MaxDate
ORDER BY t1.Item ASC
```

This statement works on both phpMyAdmin and LibreOffice base, but LibreOffice basic gives me a Message: Syntax error in SQL expression.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should remove "Price" from t2's selection. It seems nonsense in the join, and will cause error message below in MSSMS 2008 which is in my case.

> Column 'Order.Price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Try

```
SELECT t1.Item, t1.Price, t1.ODate
FROM Order AS t1
JOIN  (SELECT Item, Max(ODate) As MaxDate
        FROM Order
        GROUP BY Item ) As t2 
ON t1.Item = t2.Item and t1.Odate = MaxDate
ORDER BY t1.Item ASC
```